# Excel VBA, colour in the FIRST cell containing "IS" and "S" in a column-list

Tags: excel, vba

Column B have many cells containing "IS" and "S".  First cell B4 contains "IS", and first cell B6 contains "S", is both to be filled with colour 37.Code below: B4="IS1" is True to `1st if` and coloured; B5="IS2" is True to `2nd if` and coloured but only wanted first cell containing "IS" coloured. Please help with codes below.

```
    Dim selectedCells As Range, cell As Range
        Set selectedCells = Range("B3:B38")

'B4 = "IS1"  
'B5 = "IS2" 
'B6 = "S06"
'B7 = "S07" etc

    Dim iproColoured As Boolean, soloColoured As Boolean
        iproColoured = False
        soloColoured = False

    For Each cell In selectedCells

        If Application.IsNumber(Application.Search("IS", cell)) And iproColoured = False Then
                cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                iproColoured = True                
        End If

        If Application.IsNumber(Application.Search("S", cell)) And soloColoured = False Then
                cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                soloColoured = True
        End If

    Next cell
```

Comment: `Exit For` maybe - though do you still want `B5` to be coloured because it satisfies the 2nd `If`?

Comment: @BigBen I only want the first cell containing "IS" (B4) to be coloured.  Yes B5 satisfies 2nd if, I don't want it to be coloured.  That is the question, how to solve this problem.

Comment: Add `Exit For` within the first `If...End If`.

Comment: @BigBen  I don't know Exit For.  Please type more details on how to fix it with your suggestion

Comment: @BigBen                                                                                                          I've googled the `Exit For`.  Can't exit the for loop after the `1st if` because I need the `2nd if` to be executed to colour in the 1st cell containing "S".  That is the reason why I spent time tying the `2nd if`.

Comment: If iproColoured and soloColoured then exit for

Comment: change `If Application.IsNumber(Application.Search("S", cell)) And soloColoured = False Then` to `If Application.IsNumber(Application.Search("S", cell)) And Not Application.IsNumber(Application.Search("IS", cell)) And soloColoured = False Then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since "S" is inside "IS", as per my comment you could change:

```
If Application.IsNumber(Application.Search("S", cell)) And soloColoured = False Then
```

to:

```
If Application.IsNumber(Application.Search("S", cell)) And Not Application.IsNumber(Application.Search("IS", cell)) And soloColoured = False
```

And be sure you don't process a "IS" as an "S"

Comment: thank you! your first suggestion **If Application.IsNumber(Application.Search("S", cell)) And Not Application.IsNumber(Application.Search("IS", cell)) And soloColoured = False** works.  I've tried the **select case**, doesn't work but I've now know about **select case** and will practice with it.  Thank you very much!

Comment: The select case you suggest works too but have to include the And Not condition as well.